# Select xsl element based on index that is defined in a param

Tags: xslt, parameters

I want to select an element by index with the indexed number being passed in with a param, the param is being passed in via PHP. Here's what I am trying:

```
//PHP
$xslt->setParameter('','player',$player);
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
print $xslt->transformToXML( $data ); 

//xslt
<xsl:param name="player" data-type="number"/>

<template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="result[$player]/@name" />
</template>
```

And I know the value of the param is being passed correctly because I can just output the value of the param ($player) and it will output the correct value. If I hard code the indexed number "$player" to any number of index I want like below:

```
<template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="result[2]/@name" />
</template>
```

it works. So, what I am doing wrong here. Can you not use params/variables to select indexes?

Comment: How are you passing the param to the template? That is, how is it set?

Comment: It's being defined and set with PHP before the xlst is called.

$xslt->setParameter('','player',$player);
  
  $xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
  
  print $xslt->transformToXML( $data );

Comment: Is that template really what you are using?  A template match on the root node(i.e. `/`) that has a `select=result` will match on the document element, of which there cannot be more than one. Your select should probably be something like `*/result`, or `/*/result`, or `//result`

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and solution. I have also outlined some other parts of your code that are problematic.

Comment: Always, always provide actual input sample and stylesheet (reduce it just when it's too big). We aren't going to steal your bussines logic or to do reverse engineering with your data. In this way we can avoid having to deal with such things as evidently wrong path like `/result[2]`

Answer (score 2):

It may be evaluating the value of your xsl:param as a string, rather than a number.  You can try explicitly converting it to a number using the `number()` function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="result[number($player)]/@name" />
```

The predicate filter specifying a number is short-hand for `[position()=$param]`.  You can use `xsl:param` inside the predicate filter, like this, and it will evaluate the `xsl:param` value as a number:

```
<xsl:value-of select="result[position()=$player]/@name" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I hard code the indexed number
>   "$player" to any number of index I
>   want like below:
>
> ```
> <template match="/"> 
>     <xsl:value-of select="result[2]/@name" /> 
> </template>
> ```
>
> it works.

**No, any compliant XSLT processor will not select anything**.

```
result[2]/@name
```

is a relative expression against the current node, and the current node is the `/` -- document-node.

Any well-formed XML document has exactly one top element (never two), therefore

`result[2]`

is equivalent to:

`/result[2]`

and doesn't select anything.

Most probably you are dealing with another expression, which you haven't shown (or the template is not matching just `/`).

**Also**:

> ```
> <xsl:param name="player" data-type="number"/>
> ```

this is invalid syntax. The `<xsl:param>` instruction doesn't have a `data-type` attribute.

**In fact, in XSLT 1.0 there isn't any way to specify the type of variables or parameters**.

This is why in:

> ```
> result[$player]/@name
> ```

`$player` is treated as string -- not as an integer.

**To achieve the "indexing" you want, use**:

```
result[position()=$player]/@name
```

The `position()` function returns a number and this causes the other operand of the `=` operator to be converted to (and used as) number.